# Não é encontrado o registro no banco de dados quando o usuário efetua o login

Tags: php

Estou tentando verificar a existência de um usuário no banco de dados quando este efetua o *login*. O usuário e a senha já estão criado no banco de dados, mas mesmo assim a verificação só entra no `else`.

**logando.php**

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");
session_start();

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];


$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario` = '$usuario' AND `senha`= '$senha'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
header('location:teste1.php');
}
else{
    unset ($_SESSION['usuario']);
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
    header('location:teste2.php');

    }

?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
  include_once("conexao.php");
  session_start();
?>

<form class="login-form" name="loginform" method="post" action="logando.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="usuario" required=""/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" required=""/>
    <button type="submit">ENTRAR</button>
    <p class="message"> Desenvolvido por: Marcos A. Massini</p>
</form>

<p class="text-center text-danger">
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
            unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
        }
    ?>
</p>
```

**conexao.php**

```
<?php
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario = "root";
  $senha = "";
  $dbname = "cadastro";

  $conn = Mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname) or print (mysql_error());

  if(!Mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha)) {
    echo "Error ao conectar";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Está criptografando as senhas na hora de cadastrar no banco de dados ?

Comment: Não não, a senha esta normal, login: free senha: free, nada criptografado.

Comment: Sua conexão com o banco de dados está funcionando ?

Comment: Sim, o cadastro esta funcionando normalmente com essa conexão.

Comment: Antes da condição `if .. else` faz um `print_r($result);` ou `var_dump($result);` para saber se está retornando algo.

Comment: Opa, consegui. Coloquei da seguinte forma:

Comment: `$result = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario` = '$usuario' AND `senha`= '$senha'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);        Não sei como faz pra ficar em formato de codigo...`

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema está ocorrendo porque você não está passando os parâmetros adequados.

De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) do php, o `mysqli_query()` pede 2 argumentos:

1. `mysqli link` - O link da conexão.
2. `string query` - A query que deseja executar.

Com isso, tente executar sua query passando também o link:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario` = '$usuario' AND `senha`= '$senha'");
```